# golang sqlite can't define Query variable

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, go

It seems golang's sqlite package doesn't like my `db.Query` statement, though it's exactly like the one found in [the example on github](https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/blob/master/_example/simple/simple.go#L47).

```
db, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "./database.db")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer db.Close()

rows, err = db.Query("select id, name from job")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}   
defer rows.Close()

fmt.Println("Jobs:")
for rows.Next() {
    var name string
    var id int
    fmt.Printf("%v %v\n", id, name)
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
./test.go:7: undefined: rows
./test.go:7: cannot assign to rows
./test.go:11: undefined: rows
./test.go:14: undefined: rows
```

Edit: I've tried using grave accent and single quote strings for `db.Query()` as well, to no avail.

Comment: Look at using http://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/ to simplify the need to call `rows.Next`.

Comment: upvoted; some people don't speak compiler error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot assign values to to undeclared variables.

```
rows, err = db.Query("select id, name from job")
```

Should be :

```
rows, err := db.Query("select id, name from job")
```

Theoretically this should solve the problem, but I haven't tried.

You should also add :

```
rows.Scan(&id, &name)
```

Before the printf function so as to actually assign the row's value to the id & name variables otherwise will print an empty string & 0.

Comment: This did solve the problem. Thanks for answering, most people just downvote to oblivion. I combed through my code for about 20 minutes before asking for help. Sometimes those small syntax errors slip through the cracks.

Comment: @bvpx I answered the question because I knew how to fix your problem, but I also down voted because it was a low quality question.